# How to retrieve database value and store it for a tree datastructure?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, tree, hierarchical-data

I have some values in DB as follows 
Here parent is parent node and child is child node.

```
gid      parent    child    clientid

1         ABC       ABC       1
2         ABC       PQR       1
3         PQR        c1       1
4         PQR        c2       1
5         PQR        c3       1
6         ABC       XYZ       1
7         XYZ       EFG       1
8         EFG        c4       1
9         EFG        c5       1
```

This is the data for one tree, Here for my calculation, if parent and child are same i made it as root of the tree.

I made my own tree data structure to store all values as,

```
public class Tree<T> {

   private T head;

   private ArrayList<Tree<T>> leafs = new ArrayList<Tree<T>>();

   private Tree<T> parent = null;

   private HashMap<T, Tree<T>> locate = new HashMap<T, Tree<T>>();

   public Tree(T head) {
       this.head = head;
       locate.put(head, this);
   }
}
```

I have methods as `addleaf()` for adding nodes to the tree. `Tree` is working fine. The problem is I have to retrieve data from a database and store it in `Tree` type. For that i have done like this.

```
 Tree<String> t=null;
 Statement s = conn.createStatement();
 ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("select * from bus_serverdb.groupdet    where client_id='"+ uid + "'");
 while (rs.next()) {         
     String parent = rs.getString("parent");
     String child = rs.getString("child");   
     if(parent.equals(child)) {
        t=new Tree<String>(parent);//creates new tree with parent as root node
     }
 }
```

So now I am stuck here and I am not getting how to traverse through DB data and add it to `Tree` type. can anyone help me in this.

Comment: Do you really have a row in DB with `parent=ABC, child=ABC` ?

Comment: No line , that is the first row in DB

Comment: Yes, sorry, I had not read through the end. `ABC` is the root of the tree.

Comment: Yes, have any Idea, need help.

Answer (score 0):

If you can fetch the (parent, child) values grouped by parents, the logic of initialisation inside the `while (rs.next())` loop is:

- read *(parent, child)* pair
- find *parent* node in tree
- for all *(parent, child)* with identical *parents*

  - create a new *child node* and add it to *parent node*
  - add *(child value, child node)* to the helper `location`

In your `Tree` class, I would separate the `Tree` that holds the root node, and a `Node` class, which has a *value*, *parent* and *children* (of type `List<Node<T>>`).

Also, I think the `locate` hashmap should be part of `Tree` but not `Node`. I see it as a helper function to find quickly a `Node` by name, considering a node name as unique.